# How to combine two tables to make it as a single table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named "item" as shown below:

```
itemId  itemName
001     Chicken Chop
002     Mushroom Chicken
003     Grilled Chicken
004     Chicken Maryland
```

Then, I have a table named "genRecom" as shown below:

```
id     orderItem1   recomItem1
359    001          002
360    001,003      002
361    001          002,003
362    001          003
363    001,002      003
```

From both of the tables above, I want my table "Recom" to be as follows:

```
id     orderItem1                      recomItem1
359    Chicken Chop                    Mushroom Chicken
360    Chicken Chop, Grilled Chicken   Mushroom Chicken
361    Chicken Chop                    Mushroom Chicken, Grilled Chicken
362    Chicken Chop                    Grilled Chicken
363    Chicken Chop, Mushroom Chicken  Grilled Chicken
```

Now, I have two part of codes. The first part of code gives me this table:

```
id     orderItem1                      
359    Chicken Chop                    
360    Chicken Chop, Grilled Chicken   
361    Chicken Chop                    
362    Chicken Chop                    
363    Chicken Chop, Mushroom Chicken  

    SELECT  g1.id AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(i1.itemName) AS orderItem1
    FROM    `item` AS i1
    CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  1 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 AS pos
        ) q
    JOIN  `genRecom` AS g1
    ON    i1.itemId = CAST(NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g1.orderItem1, ',', -pos), SUBSTRING_INDEX(g1.orderItem1, ',', 1 - pos)) AS UNSIGNED)
    GROUP BY g1.id;
```

The second part of code gives me this table:

```
id     recomItem1
359    Mushroom Chicken
360    Mushroom Chicken
361    Mushroom Chicken, Grilled Chicken
362    Grilled Chicken
363    Grilled Chicken

    SELECT  g1.id AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(i1.itemName) AS recomItem1
    FROM    `item` AS i1
    CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  1 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS pos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 AS pos
        ) q2
     JOIN  `genRecom` AS g1
     ON    i1.itemId = CAST(NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g1.recomItem1, ',', -pos), SUBSTRING_INDEX(g1.recomItem1, ',', 1 - pos)) AS UNSIGNED)
     GROUP BY g1.id;
```

Does anyone know how should I combine both codes to produce a table "Recom" looks like the one I mentioned above? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` along with a basic join:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.itemName) AS orderItem1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.itemName) AS recomItem1
FROM genRecom t1
INNER JOIN item t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.itemId, t1.orderItem1) > 0
INNER JOIN item t3
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t3.itemId, t1.recomItem1) > 0
GROUP BY t1.id
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

This approach would work well assuming each item only appears once for a given row in the `genRecom` table.  If not, then you might have to build the item strings for each of the two columns in a separate subquery:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.orderItem1, t2.recomItem1
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.itemName) AS orderItem1
    FROM genRecom t1
    INNER JOIN item t2
        ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.itemId, t1.orderItem1) > 0
    GROUP BY t1.id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.itemName) AS recomItem1
    FROM genRecom t1
    INNER JOIN item t2
        ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.itemId, t1.recomItem1) > 0
    GROUP BY t1.id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This is in the case where the itemId in table "Item" is of VARCHAR data type, what if the itemId is in INT type?

Comment: I have correctly answered your question.  If not, then post your actual data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For now I store the itemId as INT data type in table "Item", so if I do the way you did, I will get "[]" as a result. So I come out with the solution (codes shown above in my question), just I have no idea how to combine that two codes to get my desired output. Haha.. Maybe I can think of change the data type of itemId to VARCHAR :)

Comment: @K.W You have a data problem, because you are trying to match the integer `1` with the string `'001'`, and they're not the same thing.  You should either use `001` everywhere, or use `1` everywhere.

Comment: Note that workarounds for this problem are possible, but very ugly, and you should really fix your data.

Comment: Noted, I will fix my data. Really thanks for your explanation :)